# Samsung Flip + Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: touchscreen, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have started to work with a brand new Samsung Flip digital paperboard (WM55H).
This device works well with my laptop (WIN10) but i would like to have another PC connected to the screen in any situation for video/content display.
I thought about raspberry Pi for that.

Is the raspberry compatible with the USB touch out function? Is there any restriction or OS i should use? 
Despite i google the questions, I don't where to start...

Thank's for your help

Comment: Did you try just plugging it into the Pi? What happens?

Comment: I dont have Pi... but I plan to buy one if it will work.

Comment: I just test it today with pi4 and... it doesn't work...
Usb touch out function is not working with screen. 
Do you have any idea?